# Strange error in BizTalk mapping

Tags: c#, biztalk

I created a map in Biztalk and tried to compile the project with it (project contains only this map).

But I have this compilation error:

> Error 1   Exception Caught: Method not found:
>   'Microsoft.BizTalk.TOM.ITOMTree
>   Microsoft.BizTalk.Mapper.OM.Map.get_TargetTree()'.

I added a reference to `Microsoft.BizTalk.TOM` and `Microsoft.BizTalk.Mapper.OM`, but this doesn't help.

Comment: try to delete the generated map.cs file and then recompile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try re-registering the Microsoft.BizTalk.TOM assembly to the GAC, re-open project and try again.